# symmetric sorting in bash

Tags: bash, sorting

I have given list of data following:

```
0.0,0.0,value
1.0,0.0,value
...
40.0,0.0,value
0.0,1.0,value
1.0,1.0,value
...
40.0,1.0,value
...
40.0,120.0,value
```

and I would like to sort second column in symmetric way, but maintain the order of first column, so the output would look like:

```
0.0,120.0,value
1.0,120.0,value
...
40.0,120.0,value
0.0,119.0,value
...
40.0,119.0,value
...
40.0,0.0,value
```

I have no idea which bash command line/script I should use.

Comment: `sort -t ',' -k2,2nr file_name`

Comment: It worked, thank you! I didn't even have to modify the command line (excepting file_name)

Comment: Glad it worked :-) ..I've updated it as Answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
sort -t ',' -k2,2nr file_name
```

Explanation:

```
-t : field-separator (here it's `,`)
-k, --key=POS1[,POS2]   Where POS1 is the starting field position, and POS2 is the ending field position
-n : numeric-sort
-r : reverse
```